# Unable to divide rasters through gdal_calc.py because of unicode error

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdal-calc

I am trying to use python in Jupyter Notebook to divide raster file A by raster file B. I am trying to use the `gdal_calc.py` program in a Jupyter Notebook cell, and not in the command line, and so I am trying to figure out the correct python syntax to carry out my intended calculation. I tried using the `subprocess()` function to carry out the command line syntax within python syntax.

I tried this so far:

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\pkgs\gdal-3.4.0-py39hd395a97_8\Scripts\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'Path\to\file\raster1.tif', '-B', 'Path\to\file\raster2.tif', '--outfile=Path\to\file\result.tif', '--calc="A/B"'])
```

And I received this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2948/1051288081.py", line 1
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\pkgs\gdal-3.4.0-py39hd395a97_8\Scripts\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'raster1.tif', '-B', 'raster2.tif', '--outfile=result.tif', '--calc="A/B"'])
                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

It seems like I used the `gdal_calc.py` arguments correctly, but is there a key syntax error I am making here that is causing this raster division calculation process to fail?

UPDATE:
I tried running this:

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:/Users/MyName/Anaconda3/pkgs/gdal-3.4.0-py39hd395a97_8/Scripts/gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'raster1.tif', '-B', 'raster2.tif', '--outfile=result.tif', '--calc="A/B"'])
```

And received an output of `1` which tells me the process failed.

Comment: Got it, I posted the updated code I just ran in my post above, and I used forward slashes this time. The code ran I am guessing, since no error message was output, but I received a `1`, which tells me the process failed. I used: `subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:/Users/MyName/Anaconda3/pkgs/gdal-3.4.0-py39hd395a97_8/Scripts/gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'raster1.tif', '-B', 'raster2.tif', '--outfile=result.tif', '--calc="A/B"'])`, and I received a `1` output, which tells me the process failed. I can't figure out which part is wrong since all the arguments are there.

Comment: Do your actual paths have any non-ASCII characters (e.g. any umlauts or accents)? e.g. `"C:/Users/Überwald/Anaconda3/pkgs/gdal-3.4.0-py39hd395a97_8/Scripts/gdal_calc.py'`

Comment: No, no special characters like that are used, just the paths themselves, I also tried listing full paths for everything like so: `subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:/Users/MyName/Anaconda3/pkgs/gdal-3.4.0-py39hd395a97_8/Scripts/gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/Folder/raster1.tif', '-B', 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/Folder/raster2.tif', '--outfile=C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/Folder/result.tif', '--calc="A/B"'])` and this still produced `1`.

Comment: Running from the command line and received this error: `<string>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide` and then received this: `ERROR 1: TIFFAppendToStrip:Maximum TIFF file size exceeded. Use BIGTIFF=YES creation option.`

`ERROR 1: result.tif, band 1: An error occurred while writing a dirty block from GDALRasterBand::RasterIO` hundreds of times, and then got: `More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.` and then a grid-looking count-up from 0 to 100, and then `Done`. Looking at the result raster in QGIS it is all blank.

Comment: Test from the command line with a small raster file to avoid the TIFF size error that may be irrelevant.